# passing and casting method pointers

Tags: c++, derived-class, base-class, pointer-to-member, member-functions

I struggle creating derived classes and passing method pointers from it to the base class, so that a function declared in the base class may call it (call the function of the derived class via interface).

The goal is to create derived classes to bring their own ressources and functions, but the call of a function declared there should be possible by calling one of them in the function the base class provides. For this i need to pass a member function pointer of the derived down to the base class.

Here's what I tried:

```
    class KeyFunction
{
    void(*KeyFunction::KeyFuncPtr)() = nullptr;   //pointer to a method of this class to store standard behavior for call

public:
    KeyFunction(void(*KeyFunction::KeyFunc)()) : KeyFuncPtr(KeyFunc)    {}                  //constructor which takes in standard behavior

    void func()       //standard call of the function
    {
        if(KeyFuncPtr)KeyFuncPtr(); //call with ensurance there's something to be called
    }

    void operator()() //make KeyFunction class callable
    {
        func();
    }
};

class customRessource{
public:
    string up = "UP";
    string down = "DOWN";

};

class customKeyFunc : public KeyFunction
{
    customRessource& r;
public:
    void moveup()               //possible behavior
    {
        cout << r.up;
    }
    void movedown()
    {
        cout << r.down;
    }

    customKeyFunc( void(*customKeyFunc::KeyFunc)() ) :KeyFunction( ( void(*KeyFunction::)() ) (KeyFunc) ){}


};

int main()
{
    customKeyFunc Up(&(customKeyFunc::moveup));   //setup functions
    customKeyFunc Down(&customKeyFunc::movedown);

    Up();                                         //call functions
    Down();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The main function at the end shows the supposed way to use the class .

First of all: my types in the constructors of each class go wild (i tried a lot of search about how to write member pointers right but i'm still not stable with the syntax)
Can someone help me get them right ?

Can I even do this (especially casting down member pointers like i did in the customKeyFunc constructor)? Am I aproaching this the right way or do I think too complicated ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to reinvent virtual methods. Reinventing the wheel is always a difficult job.

Comment: Seems like a use case for [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use virtual functions?

Comment: because i dont want to ... the problem with this is that i need to create a new class for each function (inheriting the base) even if the functions are working on the same ressource if i did virtual functions

Comment: Ok, but nothing that you wrote precludes the use of virtual methods.

Comment: You're probably right.. i tend to use virtual only when I really need it since i thought they're working on runtime

Comment: @Meph Take a look at CRTP as mentioned. It will preserve you with polymorphism, while avoiding the overheads of dynamic polymorphism as vtables or alike.

Comment: yeah i just checked what it is but i don't think it will help in my case. I created this whole type to store objects of it in an array of pointers so i can call them with my keyboard (keyboard input) efficiently. I cannot create an array of alternating types (which types created with different templates are)

Comment: Ok I could use CRTP with the downside that i would need to define one derived class with all the ressources i ever will need in my program. This would kill the feature of defining these derived classes in the ressources themself or anywhere outside this one class that defines all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class customResource{
public:
    const std::string up = "UP";
    const std::string down = "DOWN";
};

class customKeyFunc
{
    const customResource& r;
public:
  customKeyFunc(const customResource& r) : r(r) {}

  void moveup()               //possible behavior
    {
        std::cout << r.up;
    }

    void movedown()
    {
        std::cout << r.down;
    }

};

int main()
{
  customResource r;
  customKeyFunc f(r);

  auto Up = std::function<void()>(std::bind(&customKeyFunc::moveup, f));
  auto Down = std::function<void()>(std::bind(&customKeyFunc::movedown, f));

  Up();                                         //call functions
  Down();

  return 0;
}
```

`std::function<void()>` is a polymorphic functor which will copy any object that:

- is movable or copyable, and
- implements `void operator()`

Comment: Yes this works perfectly ! awesome, thank you ;D i can now define an array with this function<void()> class , which is basicaly what i wanted to create it seems.

Comment: for protocol: the actual solution to the problem itself is probably researchable in std documentations about std::functions i guess (if someone really wants to do this himself)

Comment: @Meph - yes you can create an array of std::functions. Yes the answer is in the documentation, which you should read if you want to progress...